# Angular testing of mat-checkbox correctly

Tags: angular, unit-testing, npm, checkbox, karma-jasmine

I'm wondering what is the correct way to test  about the box checked and binded value are changed?

This is my HTML

```
     <div>
      <mat-checkbox class="col-md-9 text-right" id="checkid" name="checkid"
                    [checked]="this.isChecked"
                    (change)="this.isChecked = !isChecked">
        CheckBoxLabel
      </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
```

Then I tested by

```
const checkboxElem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-checkbox')).nativeElement;
expect(checkboxElem.checked).toBeFalsy(); //pass
expect(comp.isChecked).toBeFalsy(); //pass
checkboxElem.click();
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(checkboxElem.checked).toBeTruthy(); //fail
expect(comp.isChecked).toBeTruthy(); //fail
```

The second expect always fails because the checkboxElem.checked=false all the time. I searched around 5 posts about the issue and have tried the following ways but none of those works:

1. Made this test async and add whenStable(), same result
2. Use the query By id, same result
3. Put the text in label and defined element by `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-checkbox label')).nativeElement`, same result

In the debug mode, I cannot see the box of checkbox but only the label. I'm not sure how does jasmine click that element exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `MatCheckboxModule` imported in your `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`? I would import it to render the checkbox and that way you won't only see the label. Doing this a lone might fix it.

If that doesn't fix it, I would still have the import in the `imports` array and I would do `triggerEventHandler`.

```
const checkboxElem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-checkbox'));
expect(checkboxElem.checked).toBeFalsy(); //pass
expect(comp.isChecked).toBeFalsy(); //pass
checkboxElem.triggerEventHandler('change', { }); // change this line
fixture.detectChanges();
// this bottom line will always fail because checkboxElem is now stale, 
// you need to grab a new reference
// expect(checkboxElem.checked).toBeTruthy(); //fail
const newCheckboxElem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-checkbox')).nativeElement;
expect(newCheckboxElem.checked).toBeTruthy();
expect(comp.isChecked).toBeTruthy(); //fail
```

Learn more about `triggerEventHandler` [here](https://netbasal.com/simulating-events-in-angular-unit-tests-5482618cd6c6).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, and your link is very helpful! But I imports the MatCheckModule and tried to use `triggerEventHandler`, but got the error: TypeError: checkboxElem.triggerEventHandler is not a function.

Comment: Oops, I think it should have been `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-checkbox'))` (no nativeElement, first line changed). I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I tried this and it works. Using a dispatchEvent allows clicking the checkbox and the checked status became true. This is one of the suggestions in @AliF50 's `triggerEventHandler` link.

```js
const checkboxElem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-checkbox')).nativeElement;
expect(checkboxElem.checked).toBeFalsy();

checkboxElem.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(checkboxElem.checked).toBeTruthy();
```